# Why do we sometimes define likelihood as $p(\textbf{T}|\textbf{X},w)$ and sometimes as $p(\textbf{X}, \textbf{T}|w)$?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, likelihood

Let's suppose we have a dataset $\mathcal{D}=(\textbf{X}, \textbf{T})$ where $\textbf{X}$ are the samples and $\textbf{T}$ are the targets. We want to find $w$ such that the likelihood is maximized. When doing this sort of exercises in my Machine Learning course, we sometime define likelihood as $p(\textbf{T}|\textbf{X},w)$ whereas sometimes we define it as $p(\textbf{X},\textbf{T}|w)$. Why is this a legitimate thing to do? Shouldn't the likelihood be just the latter, since our dataset is composed by both $\textbf{X}$ and $\textbf{T}$? Is there a mathematical reason why we can do this, or is it just a matter of defining it in the easiest way depending on the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is conditional joint, and can be written as $p(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{T}|w)=p(\mathbf{T}|\mathbf{X},w)P(\mathbf{X}|w)$. $w$ relates data to targets, so it's generally assumed that $p(\mathbf{X}|w)=p(\mathbf{X})$, which means the second term is nothing but a constant if we aim to maximize the expression with respect to $w$. So, both are valid and give the same $w_{ML}$ estimate.